# Membership provider does not work on the server after deployment

Tags: deployment, membership, provider

Just deployed my mvc app to a server, I have 4 services running on the server with a Connection to the DB - works fine. when I try to login ( using the Membership.ValidateUser I always get false, same goes for trying to register a user ( Does not work). In the DB I have ApplicationName ="/". My relevant configs are:

```
<membership>
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
             connectionStringName="LargainDb" 
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" `enter `enter code here`code here`
             enablePasswordReset="true" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
             minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
             applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</membership>
<profile>
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" 
             connectionStringName="LargainDb" 
             applicationName="/" />
     </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="true">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="LargainDb" 
             applicationName="/" 
             name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
             <add applicationName="/" 
                  name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" 
                  type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I tried practically everything, nothing works.
All works fine from visual studio. Can anyone help? Im desprerate.

Comment: Look at your connection string (LargainDb).  What do you mean by Register User "Does not work"?

Comment: Connection string is fine LargainDb is is the ConnecitonString Name: